# Queries with special characters not fetching data (Objective C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I am having trouble when I try to execute queries with special characters like ñ, é, etc.

The weird thing is that I am trying to fetch data with the same data that cames from the DB.

For example, I have a table "categories". In that table one of the values returned is "Música" for the field category_name.  With this data I populate a NSArray with the values in controller that populates a table view with those values. The table is showing in the data right.

Then, I need all the subcategories related to the category with category_name "Música" when a user taps in the row "Música" in my table view. I get the value clicked (NSString *)[self.data objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] and with this value I try to execute a query like:

```
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select subcategory_name from categories where category_name = '%@'", (NSString *)[self.data objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
```

It works fine when the category_name doesn't have any special character, but if the category_name has a special character it doesn't fetch any data.

Otherwise if I log the query and use the same query logged in SQLite Studio it fetchs the rows.

Does any one have any idea about what can be happening that my queries doesn't fetch the data?

Comment: use 'like' instead of '=' while matching or comparing strings in query.

Answer (score 2):

Use this to get data from database -

```
[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 4)];
```

Hope, this is what you're looking for. Any concern get back to me. :)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, it is an encoding issue.   Whatever encoding is in the database is not the encoding you are passing down in the query.

To check, you'll need to log the exact query being fed to SQLite and examine the actual bytes of the query.

(Core Data handles this kind of stuff pretty well -- writing raw SQL these days is generally a waste of time.  At least use FMDB, but I don't know if it will handle encodings any better.)

Comment: I've logued my query in this way: const char *cstr = [query UTF8String]; printf("%s\n", cstr); NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:cstr]); And the query seems to be right: select subcategory_name from categories where category_name = 'Música'

Comment: That won't help;  you are explicitly causing a conversion to `UTF8` in that logging code.  You need to look at the raw bytes as they are sent to SQLite.